# Memory Access Violation when creating a Link List from a File in C

Tags: c, list, hyperlink

Hello I'm having some issues working with loading a struct linked list in C with the contents of a file that's created after program is run initially.  I've been working on this for a few days and seem to not understand what I'm doing wrong because I believe this should be working.  I keep getting memory access violations and I'm assuming this is either coming from how I'm using my node to fill the struct or I'm not freeing the memory when the program exits.  This is a homework assignment and I know you guys frown upon these types of questions so feel free not to answer and think I'm an idiot.  I'm not looking for answers but I am clearly not understanding something.

One last thing is that the reason my file close is commented is that when it is active I don't see what my program print to console.  Without it I am able to see the output of the file until it hits the end of the newly created link list from the file.

{

```
FILE* filename;                                 //create FILE pointer               
struct PlayerTime *node, *temp;                 //create a PlayerTime struct pointer node
char sname[MAX_STR_LEN];                        //specifies type of data to be stored
float stime;                                    //specifies type of data to be stored
filename = fopen("SAVE_TIMES.txt", "rb");       //sets saveTimes pointer = to an open file

if(filename != NULL)                                //if file is there
{   
    while((fread(sname, MAX_STR_LEN, 1, filename)) == 1)        
    {           
        node = (struct PlayerTime *) malloc(sizeof(struct PlayerTime));     //create a node

        strcpy(node->name, sname);                                          //copies name data from file into node
        fread(&stime, sizeof(float), 1, filename);                          //reads time and passed by reference
        node->seconds = stime;                                              //copies seconds data from file into node

         if(list_head != NULL)                                              //loop reads PlayerTime lis_head
        {
            temp->next = node;                                              //loop fills struct with saved times
        }
        else
            list_head = node;
        temp = node;
    }   
    //fclose(filename);                 
}
```

}

Comment: Might be handy to include `struct PlayerTime` declaration in the posted code

Comment: Also consider using the debugger

Answer (score 0):

When you get an access violation, the easiest way to figure out what went wrong is to fire up your debugger. On Linux this would be gdb.

```
gdb ./YourProgram
```

In gdb:
    run

When you get a segfault, just type

```
backtrace
```

and you get a stack dump, indicating where the bad stuff happened.

My first guess would be that

```
temp->next = node;
```

causes the access violation, but I'm not sure since I don't know when you set list_head.